# PHP Array Loop Help - WordPress ACF

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a leaderboard in WordPress. The user submits their mileage along with the date and method in an ACF repeater field. I am pulling the data and need to output the following $leaderboard array:

```
Array ( [user1] => Array ( [walking] => 2 [overall_mileage] => 11 [swimming] => 9 ) [user2] => Array ( [running] => 54.25 [overall_mileage] => 54.25 ) )
```

I am calculating the mileage and inserting it into the array.

What's the best way to loop through this into a table so that it displays in a leaderboard with a breakdown as follows?

USERNAME | SWIMMING | WALKING | RUNNING | OVERALL MILES

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you explain the expected output ?

Comment: Just update the question.